# Prove that $\{ x: f(x) < a \}$ is an open set. Prove that $\{ x: f(x) = a \}$ is a Borel set.

Tags: real-analysis, semicontinuous-functions

A function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^*$ ($\Bbb R^*$ is the reals together with $\pm\infty$) is upper semicontinuous at $y$ if

$f(y)\neq +\infty$ and
$f(y) \geq \limsup\limits_{x\to y} f(x)$.
Let $a \in \Bbb R^*$.

Prove that $\{ x: f(x) < a \}$ is an open set. 
Prove that $\{ x: f(x) = a \}$ is a Borel set.

Comment: "=/=" means "$\neq$"?

Comment: The range of $f$ has to be $\mathbb R \cup \{-\infty,+\infty\}$ for your definition to make sense.

Comment: @TonyK Is $\Bbb R^*$ good for you?

Comment: Jason, I edited to add $\LaTeX$. Is everything OK?

Comment: @Brian I wrote $\limsup$ first, but then flinched. Thanks.

Comment: @Peter: I'm not familiar with the $\mathbb R^*$ notation. But in any case the function is described as "f: R->R" in the first line. So how could $f(y)$ ever equal $+\infty$?

Comment: @TonyK I think I saw it in Rudin's or Apostol's Analysis, to symbolize the extended reals.

Comment: Closely related question - but it uses a different (but probably equivalent) definition of semicontinuity: [Show that if $f^{-1}((\alpha, \infty))$ is open for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is lower-semicontinuous](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123379/show-that-if-f-1-alpha-infty-is-open-for-any-alpha-in-mathbbr)

Comment: The question is still incomplete. Is $f$ supposed to be upper semi-continuous everwhere? The question doesn't say so. Also, is the domain of $f$ really $\mathbb R^*$, as per Brian's edit? Normally it would just be $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @TonyK: I doubt it; I'm just not quite awake yet. It seems likely that $f$ is upper semicont. everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f$ is upper semicontinous; then for each $x_0\in\Bbb R$ and $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)\le f(x_0)+\epsilon$ whenever $|x-x_0|<\delta$. Fix $a\in\Bbb R^*$, and let $L=\{x:f(x)<a\}$; we wish to show that $L$ is open. Let $x_0\in L$ be arbitrary. Let $\epsilon=\frac12(a-f(x_0))$; $x_0\in L$, so $f(x_0)<a$, and $\epsilon>0$. Can you finish the argument from there? I've completed it but left it spoiler-protected.

> By hypothesis there is a $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)\le f(x_0)+\epsilon$ whenever $|x-x_0|<\delta$. But $$f(x_0)+\epsilon=f(x_0)+\frac12\Big(a-f(x_0)\Big)=\frac12\Big(f(x_0)+a\Big)<a\;,$$ so $f(x)<a$ whenever $|x-x_0|<\delta$, and therefore $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ is an open interval around $x_0$ contained in $L$. Since $x_0$ was an arbitrary point of $L$, $L$ is open.

For the second result, let $E=\{x:f(x)=a\}$. Observe that

$$E=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}\{x:f(x)<a+2^{-n}\}\cap\Big(\Bbb R\setminus\{x:f(x)<a\}\Big)\;,$$

and apply the first part of the problem.