# A sequential characterization of upper semi-continuous function and openness of level set

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf, semicontinuous-functions

**Question**:

****$(x_n \rightarrow x \implies \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty } f(x_n) \leq f(x) ) \implies \{x \in X |f(x) < c\} \,\text{is open for any}\, c \in R ?$****

---

I know related questions have been touched open in upper semi-continuity functions , but most of them proved the opposite direction, and I haven't managed to find a satisfying proof for this one.

**Can anyone help me with a simple but rigorous proof?**

Related MSE Post:

[Equivalence of definitions for upper semicontinuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330904/equivalence-of-definitions-for-upper-semicontinuity)

[Show that if $f^{-1}((\alpha, \infty))$ is open for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is lower-semicontinuous.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123379/show-that-if-f-1-alpha-infty-is-open-for-any-alpha-in-mathbbr?rq=1)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It can be easily proved by contradiction.

If $W_c=\{x\in X: f(x)<c\}$ is not open, for some $c\in\mathbb R$, then there exist a $\xi\in W_c$, i.e. $f(\xi)<c$, such that $B_\varepsilon(\xi)\not\subset W_c$, for every $\varepsilon>0$. In partiucular, for $\varepsilon=1/n$, there would exist an $\xi_n\in X$, such that $d(\xi_n,\xi)<1/n$, and $\xi_n\not\in W_c$, i.e. $f(\xi_n)\ge c$. But clearly, $\xi_n\to\xi$, and due to the given condition, we would have that
$$
c\le \limsup f(\xi_n)\le f(\xi)<c.
$$
Contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

To show $\{x\in X : f(x) <c\}$ is open, it is enough to show that $B=\{x\in X : f(x) \ge c\}$ is closed.

Proof : Let $\alpha \in B'$ i.e $\alpha$ is a limit point of $B$ .

To show $\alpha\in B$ .

Since $\alpha\in B'$, $\exists (x_n) \in B$ such that $x_n\to \alpha$

Then by the hypothesis, $\limsup f(x_n)\le f(\alpha)$

As $(x_n) \in B$ , $f(x_n) \ge c$

$c\le \limsup f(x_n)$

Then $c\le \limsup f(x_n)\le f(\alpha)$

Hence $f(\alpha) \ge c$ implies $\alpha \in B$

Thus the set $B$ closed. (Proved!)